# Cant "give" null value in a field of my sql table phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Im using phpmyadmin and I have a table categories with 4 fields:

**->** id

**->** id_father_category (I put this with predefined: NULL) and I also put a checkbox Null

**->** name

**->** content

I want to give null values to my **id_father_category field**.

**But Im having this error:**

**Warning:** #1366 Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'id_father_category field' at row 1

And my field id_father_category stays automatically with value 0, and I dont want that.

Somebody there knows how I can solve this problem?

Comment: What is the code you're trying ?

Comment: Im not using php code for now, and in phpmyadmin Im using the interface and not the sql code!

Comment: Did you index the column?

Comment: Well first you need to update your table to remove empty values. Stop using the UI, you're going to have a bad time.

Comment: From the error message it's clear that you don't assign NULL at all: you assign an empty string! You simply can't stuff strings in numeric columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `categories` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_father_category` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `content` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Hope this will solve your problem...

Comment: To add to this answer. You can alter your table instead of recreating it.

Comment: Yes... ALTER TABLE  `categories` CHANGE  `id_father_category`  `id_father_category` INT( 11 ) NULL DEFAULT NULL ;

Comment: Yes..It works thank you! Im not very accustomed to use sql code, so I was trying to find the solution in the interface..but I see now that maybe is better start to use the sql code instead!

Comment: @John23 Sometimes folks get lost in the UI that is phpmyadmin and the underlying sql. I would recommend using something more "sql" and user oriented like Mysql workbench, sqlyog, etc.

Answer (score 2):

This is an addition to @Nirjhor's answer.

> ALTER TABLE categories MODIFY id_father_category INT(11) DEFAULT NULL;

or you can recreate the whole thing:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `categories` (   
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,   
`id_father_category` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,   
`name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,   
`content` varchar(256) NOT NULL,   
PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ) 
ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Setting the default value to NULL will handle your issue as well as set the field to NULL. One thing to note here is to make sure you don't have some weird index on that field cause that can also create an issue.